# Setting with Copy Warning in Pandas despite using .loc

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe, df. I applied a function to the selected columns, created new columns 'est_arr_date' and 'act_arr_date' and wrote the values. I then calculated the date difference between the 2 newly created columns and have the values written to a new column, 'delta'. This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "estimated_arrival_date": [
            "2018-06-30T00:00:00",
            "2018-07-01T00:00:00",
            "2018-07-02T00:00:00",
            "2018-07-02T00:00:00",
            "2018-07-02T00:00:00",
            "2018-07-01T00:00:00",
        ],
        "actual_arrival_date": [
            "2018-07-01T00:00:00",
            "2018-07-01T00:00:00",
            "2018-07-01T00:00:00",
            "2018-07-01T00:00:00",
            "2018-07-01T00:00:00",
            "2018-07-01T00:00:00",
        ],
    }
)


def convert_StrTime(str_tme):
    """This is the helper function."""
    tme = str_tme[0:10]
    convert_tme = datetime.datetime.strptime(tme, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    return convert_tme


df.loc[:, "est_arr_date"] = df.loc[:, "estimated_arrival_date"].apply(convert_StrTime)
df.loc[:, "act_arr_date"] = df.loc[:, "actual_arrival_date"].apply(convert_StrTime)
df["delta"] = df["est_arr_date"] - df["act_arr_date"]
```

What I don't get is this error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Can someone explain this to me? I thought I am already using the .loc as recommended?

Comment: I think there si some problem above this line of code, can you add 5 6 rows above your code sample?

Comment: Hi @jezrael, added the DF as requested. I get my output DF, just that it bugs me not understanding why I get this error. Thanks!

Comment: Running the code above does not trigger a warning. Maybe the warning comes from another line in your program?

Comment: @w-m Hi! I just ran those 3 lines and it triggers the warning.

Comment: Maybe the `df` you ran it on is not a DataFrame (like from the example above), but already a slice? -> Do you get the warning also if you run just the code above (definition of df, definition of helper, three lines)?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your example. I don't get a warning